# Merging lists of data.table by list ID in R

Tags: r, data.table

I searched thoroughly SO, but I have to say the searching is increasingly difficult. However this is pretty straightforward for most of you!

The data I have looks like this:

```
library(data.table)

dataX <- data.table(V1 = "Tuesday", a2012 = rnorm(1), a2011 = rexp(1,2))
dataY <- data.table(V1 = "Monday", a2012 = rnorm(1), a2011 = rexp(1,2),a2010 = rbinom(1,2,0.3))
data1 <- list(dataX, dataY)
names(data1) <- c(123,456)
ListData <- rep(data1,6)
```

I have multiple lists of data.tables and I would like to merge them. Here how

How to merge the multiple lists of data.tables by the ID?

This is what I would like to get:

```
 $`123`

        V1     a2012     a2011   
 1: Tuesday 0.4943128 0.1045589
 2: Tuesday -0.864036 0.2515042  
 3: Tuesday -0.864036 0.2515042
```

Comment: I find this question unclear. There is no "ID" in 'data1'. You have apparently altered a data-object in your workspace and are now expecting us to log in to your computer to help. On my machine `names(data1)` returns: `NULL`. Perhaps you are just looking for the `names<-` function?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I thought that one could easily assign any name/ID for the list.

Comment: How difficult is it for you to generate the data you talk about in your post? And to show the expected output? Could you edit your post to get things clearer?

Comment: I'm sorry! Now corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like by merge you actually mean `rbind` and want:

```
rbindlist(ListData[names(ListData) == '123'])
```

Or if you want this done for all names:

```
lapply(unique(names(ListData)),
       function(n) rbindlist(ListData[names(ListData) == n]))
```

Comment: Great.The second line is what I was after.Thanks!